# Setting up headset for surround audio

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I've got a sennheiser GSP 350. It should have digital surround 7.1 on it. However, in pulseaudio, I only have the option for the build-in audio, not the headset. For the headset, i can have stereo only. Is there something I'm missing? It's usb, does that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sennheiser GSP 350 is a **stereo** headset (with "virtual" 7.1 Dolby Surround Sound), so it only has 2 audio channels as far as Ubuntu is concerned.  Choose the stereo headset option and the headset may process the audio to feel like 7.1 surround (but of course you won't get true 7.1 surround without actually having 7 different speakers).

You may also want to check out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SurroundSound for more info

Comment: Any idea how I would go about simulating it virtually ? I've tried some stuff but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: The GSP 350 comes with a Surround Dongle to toggle between stereo and "Dolby 7.1 Surround Sound".  See the Product Page (https://en-us.sennheiser.com/gaming-headset-gsp-350) for more info, instructions, etc

Comment: The dongle doesn't work on linux, it requires a windows-only software. If it's a stereo headset then I assume this toggles the "virtual" surround, which I can't figure out how to do on linux

Comment: Unfortunately, it sounds like since that specific driver is windows-only, you won't be able to get the same virtual surround software running.  However, you may be able to configure an alternative.  Take a look around at some of the help pages ( such as https://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/how-to-get-virtual-surround-sound-on-your-headphones-plugged-to-your-linux-rig or https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2267902) if you are comfortable editing configurations.

Comment: So the headset works in stereo on Ubuntu? What about microphone does it also work?

Answer (score 0):

check audio devices in ALSA

`aplay -l`

if USB headset only shows one sub-device for playback in ALSA, headset is stereo only

alleged surround-sound is probably software fakery and/or marketing nonsense

There is a Pulseaudio module [module-virtual-surround-sink](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index48h3)
 
module also needs to an HRIR file to create the surround sound profile